# Game with 6 dice, what is the chance to get a score below $10$

Tags: game-theory, dice

You are given 6 dice (with values 1 to 6) and your goal is to get a total number of pips that is less than 10.

You start by rolling all 6 dice. Say you get $(1,1,2,5,6,6)$. You may (in fact, you must) now choose one number, and put all dice with that number of pips to the side. Say you choose 1, for example. Then $(1,1)$ is put aside. You roll the remaining 4 dice again. Now you might get $(2,4,4,5)$. Again, you choose one number, say 2, and put aside all dice with that number of pips. You now have $(1,1,2)$ on the side and 3 dice left to roll. You repeat this procedure until you can throw no more dice. For instance, if you would now roll the 3 dice and get $(4,4,4)$, we can put all fours to the side and our total score will be the sum of $(1,1,2,4,4,4)$, which is $16$ in this case. The goal is to get a score $<10$.

**The question is: what is the best strategy in order to have the highest change of getting below 10? And with this strategy, what is your chance to get a score $<10$?**

Some quick simulations show that if your strategy is to *always* set aside the smallest number that appears on at least one of the rolled dice, then your chance of winning is roughly about 30%. I think there are some cases, though, in which this is not the best strategy. But I haven't seen a nice way to formulate it mathematically.

Comment: Well, to give an obvious example, if you threw all $6's$ you shouldn't set anything aside.  Or even all $2's$, come to that.

Comment: Thanks, In fact I'm assuming you must necessarily set aside something each time, but I see this was not clear from the description.

Comment: Even if you must set aside some value...if you threw, say, $3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6$  I'd set aside the $4$, not the $3's$.  Setting aside the $3's$ has no chance of winning (granted, setting aside the $4$ doesn't have much hope but at least it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can compute your maximum chance of winning, and the corresponding optimal strategy, by using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to work backwards from the final throw.  Let $\ G(d,t)\ $ denote the game in which you start with $\ d\ $ dice, and win whenever your ultimate total is less than $\ t\ $, and let $\ w(d,t)\ $ be the probability that you win when you play optimally in that game.  If you throw your $\ d\ $ dice in that game, the probability that you will get $\ n_1,$$n_2,$$\,\dots,$$n_6\ $ of each of the sides $\ 1,$$2,$$\,\dots,$$6\ $, respectively $\Big($with $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^6n_i=d\ \Big)$,  is
$$
p\big(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_6\big)=\frac{{d\choose n_1}{d-n_1\choose n_2}\dots{d-n_1-n_2\dots-n_4\choose n_5}}{6^d}\ .
$$
If you now choose to set aside the dice showing side $ i\ $ (where $\ n_i>0\ $), you will then be faced with trying to win the game $\ G(d-n_i,t-in_i)\ $, which you will do with probability $\ w(d-n_i,t-in_i)\ $ if you play optimally from then onwards.  If $\ n_i=d\ $ then you win immediately if $\ t-in_i>0\ $, or lose immediately if $\ t-in_i\le0\ $, so we set $\ w(0,t)=1\ $ for $\ t>0 $ and $\ w(0,t)=0\ $ for $\ t\le0 $.  Obviously, your optimal first move in $\ G(d,t)\ $ is to choose the value of $\ i\ $ with $\ n_i>0\ $ which maximises $\ w(d-n_i,t-in_i)\ $.  Let $\ c^*(\boldsymbol{n})\ $ be the optimal choice of $\ i\ $ for the throw $\ \boldsymbol{n}=\big(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_6\big)\ $. Then
$$
w(d,t)=\sum_\boldsymbol{n}p(\boldsymbol{n})w\big(d-n_{c^*(\boldsymbol{n})},c^*(\boldsymbol{n})n_{c^*(\boldsymbol{n})}\big)\ .
$$
Once $\ w\big(d',t'\big)\ $ has been tabulated for $\ d'<d\ $ and $\ t'<t\ $, this equation can be used to determine the value of $\ w(d,t)\ $.

The table below gives the values of $\ w(d,t)\ $ for $\ 1\le d\le4\ $ and $\ 2\le t\le11\ $, and approximate values (correct to $7$ decimal places) for $\ d=5,6\ $ and $\ 2\le t\le11\ $.  The entry for $\ d=6\ $ and $\ t=10\ $ indicates that your chance of winning the game $\ G(6,10)\ $ is only $17$-$18\%$, which is inconsistent  with the OP's statement that your chance of winning it is about $30\%$ if you always choose the smallest number that appears on at least one dice.  The table was computed with a script, but I have verified that the entries for $\ d=2\ $ and $\ 3\le t\le7\ $, and $\ d=3\ $ and $\ t=6,7\ $ are correct by hand, so I'm reasonably confident the numbers are all correct.  One possible explanation for the discrepancy is that the OP's quick simulations counted a win as occurring when the total was less than *or equal to* $10$, rather than *strictly less than* $10$.  The table entry for $\ d=6\ $ and $\ t=11\ $ indicates that, with best play, your chances of winning that game are $\ 27$-$28\%\ $.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
\hline
1&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{5}{6}&1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
2&0&\frac{2}{27}&\frac{17}{108}&\frac{8}{27}&\frac{23}{54}&\frac{16}{27}&\frac{79}{108}&\frac{23}{27}&\frac{49}{54}&\frac{26}{27}\\
\hline
3&0&0&\frac{163}{3888}&\frac{769}{7776}&\frac{761}{3888}&\frac{2431}{7776}&\frac{875}{1944}&\frac{511}{864}&\frac{5593}{7776}&\frac{6355}{7776}\\
\hline
4&0&0&0&\frac{35387}{2^63^9}&\frac{177793}{2^73^9}&\frac{185101}{2^63^9}&\frac{25565}{2^43^8}&\frac{926741}{2^73^9}&\frac{626611}{2^63^9}&\frac{197237}{2^43^9}\\
\hline
5&0&0&0&0&\tiny0.0210745&\tiny0.0551424&\tiny0.1185422&\tiny0.2025660&\tiny0.3128971&\tiny0.4353564\\
\hline
6&0&0&0&0&0&\tiny0.0170844&\tiny0.0459158&\tiny0.1008971&\tiny0.1759971&\tiny0.2767458\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
While there's  unlikely to be any simple formula for the optimal strategy for general $\ d\ $ and $\ t\ $, it turns out that for $\ G(6,10)\ $ the best moves are independent of your current position and can be succinctly described by ordering the non-fatal ones from best to worst:
$$
\{1,1^2,1^3,1^4,1^5,1^6\}\succ\{2,2^2\}\succ\{3\}\succ\{2^3\}\succ\{4\}\ .
$$
Any moves not in the above list will result in a sure loss from any position, and all moves in the above list except the $1$s can become non-viable as the game proceeds. The moves $\ \{2^3\}\ $ and $\ \{4\}\ $, for instance, will only remain viable as long as the dice that have so far been saved are all $1$s.